# Instantiate a variable in a child class

Tags: java, instantiation

is possible to instantiate a variable in a child class that was declared in the parent class? What would be the advantage?
Ex:

```
public class Animal{ Food foodType;}
public class Dog extends Animal{ 
   public Dog(){
       foodType=new Food();
   }
}
```

Comment: It's possible if the variable is visible to the child.

Comment: @nickb It's not instantiated yet.

Comment: If the modifier of property is protected, you can do it. If it is default, you can do it if your child is in the same package of parent. Ofcourse if it is public, you can do it everywhere.

Comment: @Paulo , thanks, but my question was less about modifiers.My question was why would somebody would implement that why(declaring in parent and instantiate in child).

Comment: @Toris - So? That doesn't affect how the child can instantiate it...

Comment: @Paulo pass Animal instance or something like that is needed.

Comment: @Alexis - I'm not sure you're going to get a definitive answer on 'why' somebody would instantiate a variable in a child class that's defined in the parent. There are a variety of different reasons to do so, it ultimately depends on the design of the classes and the requirements for their functionality.

Comment: @Alexis Please edit your question, It looks like Dog extends nothing.

Comment: May be it is a common field for 2 childs and  will be instantiated differently, as food = new Bread (); and food = new Meat ();

Comment: If the parent class is abstract or an interface, then you may _have_ to instantiate it in the subclass. This would require that all subclasses have their own implementation of Food, which could also be abstract or an interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of advantage of doing it. Actually depends on your design.

I created an example, maybe the worse example that I could, but I think it will make you clarify your mind. I just tried to follow your code.

In this example we use `Strategy` design pattern and `Inversion of Control`. You can see that Animal doesn't know nothing about Food implementation? Think about it, `Animal.eat()` can run multiple implementations without changing the `eat()` method. It is a little bit what the OOP can do.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args){
        Animal paul = new Dog("Paul");
        Animal elsa = new Cat("Elsa");

        paul.eat();
        elsa.eat();
    }

    public static abstract class Animal {
        private String name;
        protected Food foodType;

        public Animal(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void eat() {
            System.out.println("The " + name + " has eaten " + foodType.getAmount() + " " + foodType.foodName());
        }
    }

    public static class Dog extends Animal {
        public Dog(String name) {
            super(name);
            foodType = new DogFood();
        }
    }

    public static class Cat extends Animal {
        public Cat(String name) {
            super(name);
            foodType = new CatFood();
        }
    }

    public interface Food {
        int getAmount();
        String foodName();
    }

    public static class DogFood implements Food{
        @Override
        public int getAmount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public String foodName() {
            return "beef";
        }
    }

    public static class CatFood implements Food{
        @Override
        public int getAmount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public String foodName() {
            return "fish";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. The Inversion of Control is a martian expression for me :)

Comment: `Inversion of Control` is simple to understand. As rule, if an object can execute differents implementation without change its class, this class is implementing `IoC`. An example is the `Thread.class`, it uses  `IoC` to handle the execution of `Runnable` implementation without knowing anything about this implementation.

Comment: Thanks, pretty simple, huh... More personal question: how long does it take to understand the design patterns and to use them properly? Just a clue...

Answer (score 0):

advantage:

For ex.
If there is DogFood class extends Food, Dog can instantiate it (if Dog knows about DogFood) and Animal does not need to know about DogFood.

This simplifies codes.

Answer (score 0):

As food type is an Animal property, and always the same for a specific child class, make it `final` in Animal, and pass it in via the Animal constructor.

```
public class Animal {
    public final Food foodType;

    public Animal(Food foodType) {
        this.foodType = foodType;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{ 
    public Dog() {
       super(new DogFood());
    }
}
```

Now every Animal (child) has a foodType, and one does not have to fill the field of a parent class. The responsibilities are where they should be.